# Change format of DateTime value

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, ms-access

Everybody seems to hate `DateTime` values.

In my project, I have a `SQL SELECT` query to find results in the database matching the parameter values.

The code I have is:

```
Dim where As String = "WHERE [Supp_Code] = @scode " & _
    "AND [DateFrom] = @datfrom " & _
    "AND [DateTo] = @datto " & _
    "AND [Comm_Code] = @ccode " & _
    "AND [Customer_Code] = @custcode "

Dim sql As String = "SELECT [Comm_Code], [AqYear] FROM [Acquisition Commission] "

sql &= where & " ORDER BY [AqYear] ASC"

Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scode", cmbSupp.Text.Trim)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datfrom", datFrom.Value)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datto", datTo.Value)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccode", txtCommCode.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custcode", cmbCustomerCode.Text)

Dim daYear As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dsYear As New DataSet
daYear.Fill(dsYear)
```

The code itself has no issues. The issue is that the `DataSet` only ever has 0 rows, because the `DateTime` format of `datFrom.Value` (which is a `DateTimePicker` control) is 'MM/dd/yyyy', but in the database it is stored as 'dd/MM/yyyy'.

What's the easiest way of converting it the correct database format before using it as a parameter?

**EDIT**

Using the comments/answers below, I've adapted my code to the following:

```
 Dim test As DateTime
 Dim test2 As DateTime
    test = ugDates.ActiveRow.Cells("DateFrom").Value
    test = ugDates.ActiveRow.Cells("DateTo").Value

 Try
  Dim where As String = "WHERE [Supp_Code] = @scode " & _
       "AND [DateFrom] = @datfrom " & _
       "AND [DateTo] = @datto " & _
       "AND [Comm_Code] = @ccode " & _
       "AND [Customer_Code] = @custcode "

Dim sql As String = "SELECT DISTINCT [Comm_Code], [AqYear] FROM [Acquisition Commission] "

    sql &= where & " ORDER BY [AqYear] ASC"

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@scode", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbSupp.Text
     cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@datfrom", OleDbType.Date).Value = test)
     cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@datto", OleDbType.Date).Value = test2)
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@ccode", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCommCode.Text
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@custcode", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbCustomerCode.Text
```

But, it gives me the following error on the second parameter:

> The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not Boolean objects.

Comment: will datFrom.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") suffice?

Comment: See [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I hope your date columns use a date column type (and not varchar/string)?

Comment: @HansKesting Yes they are DateTime values in the database

Comment: @krishKM No, I tried this, I thought it would but for some reason didn't

Comment: Its the 2 lines `cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@datfrom", ...`,

Comment: @Igor I did that, but as I mentioned below it didn't like that, It said Value is not defined and didn't like the ; at the end

Comment: @David - got it, see the code below done on one line using `with` as the initializer in vb.net

Comment: @Igor Yep, thank you, solved it

Comment: `test = ugDates.ActiveRow.Cells("DateFrom").Value` `test = ugDates.ActiveRow.Cells("DateTo").Value` - shouldn't that second assignment be `test2 = ...` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The issue is that the DataSet only ever has 0 rows, because the DateTime format of datFrom.Value (which is a DateTimePicker control) is 'MM/dd/yyyy', but in the database it is stored as 'dd/MM/yyyy'.

That is probably NOT the issue unless you are storing the date as a string. A date is a structure, not a string, and inherently does not have formatting. Formatting is something that is applied to a string. Its similar to a number like an int or decimal. If this field is indeed a string you should revisit your schema and update the type accordingly.

Most likely you are trying to compare a date with time either in the value of the parameter OR in the value of the query.

- Use `DateValue` function to trim the time of the stored database
- Use `.Date` on the date value to only compare the value date

Code:

```
Dim where As String = "WHERE [Supp_Code] = @scode " & _
        "AND DateValue([DateFrom]) = @datfrom " & _ 
        "AND DateValue([DateTo]) = @datto " & _
        "AND [Comm_Code] = @ccode " & _
        "AND [Customer_Code] = @custcode "


// select either OleDbType.Date or OleDbType.DBDate

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@datfrom", OleDbType.Date) With {.Value = datFrom.Value.Date})
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@datto", OleDbType.Date) With {.Value = datTo.Value.Date})
```

---

The other possible problem is the logic, why not do a between or range check instead of an equality check on `DateFrom` and `DateTo`?

```
"AND DateValue([DateFrom]) >= @datfrom " & _ 
"AND DateValue([DateTo]) <= @datto " & _
```

Ideally you would use the same value here for both `@datfrom` and `@datto`. The query above would be any item that has a start/end date that span the passed in date parameter.

Comment: Thank you for this. When doing the `{Value = datFrom...` part of this code, Value has an error -Value is not declared - and under the ; it says operator is not valid.. Is this in C#?

Comment: @David - it could be that the control `datFrom` does not have a selected value in which case trying to retrieve the date part from the `DateTime` with `datFrom.Value.Date` will fail with an NRE (NullReferenceException). Have you checked that the date picker has a date selected and that the `.Value` is of type `DateTime`?

Comment: Okay, I've done some editing... The question above now may make the issue easier to diagnose